# first order equivalence question

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

If we know that
$C\models A$ and   $C\not\models B$

Can we say that $C\models A$ and  $C\not\models B$ iff $C\models B\rightarrow A$ and   $C\not\models B$ ?

Edit:
Can we say that $C\models A$ and  $C\not\models \lnot B$ iff $C\models B\rightarrow A$ and   $C\not\models \lnot B$ ?

Answer (score 1):

No. One direction of the biconditional fails. From $C \vDash B \to A$ and $C \nvDash B$ it doesn't follow that $C \vDash A$.

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are the same. Then we'd trivially have $C \vDash A \to A$; but that with $C \nvDash A$ wouldn't imply $C \vDash A$!

Added: on the edited addition, no. The same direction of the biconditional fails. Again suppose $A$ and $B$ are the same. Then we'd trivially have $C \vDash A \to A$; but that with $C \nvDash \neg A$ wouldn't imply $C \vDash A$! $A$ can be independent of $C$, so $C$ entails neither it nor its negation.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. Were we to hold that C⊭¬B, we should get the equivalence right, or am I missing something?